# How could I export Excel file when I get the information on table html (webbrowser)

Tags: c#, export

I create a form(home) and enter URL to get inside the website. I also create 10 tabs.So when I click to see information in home. it will display 10 Ids example like "100210323232".and inside each Ids have detail information about company name ,adress ... When i click button( I create a button ). The detail information of these ids will display in 10 tabs.

Finally I want to export these detail information to excel file.

The detal information table: [link](https://gyazo.com/89cf839bd40970a65360312f586340f1). And code display detail information in 10 tab

```
        var content1 = wb.Document.GetElementById("content").InnerHtml; 
        Regex regex1 = new Regex("<TD.*><A.*>(.*)</A></TD>"); 
        Regex regex2 = new Regex("<TD.*><A href=\"(.*)\">.*</A></TD>"); 
        var run = 0;
        var intobj = 1;
        object[] obj = new object[10];
        foreach (Match match1 in regex1.Matches(content1.ToString())) 
        {
            run++;
            if (run == 5) 
            {
                Match match2 = regex2.Match(match1.Value);
                switch (intobj)
                {
                    case 1:
                        wb1.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        wb2.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        wb3.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        wb4.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        wb5.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        wb6.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        wb7.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        wb8.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        wb9.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        wb10.Navigate(match2.Groups[1].Value.Replace("amp;", "&"));
                        break;
                }
                intobj++;
                run = 0; // back run về 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to export data you captured to Excel.

The easy way to do this is to write data out to CSV format and let Excel do the hard work for you.

Try something along this line:

```
String header = "Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4"; // just change this to whatever you want
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(header);
foreach (Match match1 in regex1.Matches(content1.ToString())) 
{
   sb.Append(match1.Groups[1].value).Append(",");
}
File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```